# Unsupported Media Type on ASP.Net Core 2.2 ApiController

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have the following controller and actions:

```
[ApiController, ApiVersion("1.0", Deprecated = false), Route("v{version:version}")]
public class PostController : ControllerBase {

  [HttpGet("users/{userId}/posts")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetByUserId(GetModel model) {

  }

  [HttpPost("users/{userId}/posts")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> CreateByUserId(CreateModel model) {

  }

}
```

I tried to access both actions using Angular and [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest) ...

I am able to access CreateByUserId [POST] but I get an error on GetByUserId [GET]:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
  "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "status": 415,
  "traceId": "0HLMF7BM7U94L:00000001"
}
```

What am I missing? The action is a simple Get action.

Comment: I found the problem, Needed to have [FromQuery] before the GetModel

Comment: I saw your question. After then I added [FromBody] before my model. It worked. If anyone faces like this error , it can use that code.