# Fetch POST ReactJs to Controller .Net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have problem in Fetch POST to controller, an showing error like `{"errors":{"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: W. Path '', line 1, position 6."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"0HLOGKVEBUTKL:00000007"}`. When I debbug too, in my controller it's not passing to controller.

This what I POST to

[image]
[image]

I'm using ReactJs for client-side, and Net Core for server-side. Here my code snippet:

AddList.js

```
 fetch('api/SampleData/AddEmployee', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
   },
   body: data,
 }).then((response) => response.json())
 .then((responseJson) => {
   console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(responseJson));
   this.props.history.push("/list-data");
 })
   .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

SampleDataController.cs

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public JsonResult AddEmployee(EmployeesViewModel employee)
{
}
```

starrup.cs

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
 {
   routes.MapRoute(
     name: "default",
     template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

   routes.MapRoute(
     name: "api",
     template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
 });
```

Comment: can you try it without `Content-Type`. It worked for me when i was dealing with formdata

Comment: different error `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"0HLOGKVEBUTKP:00000008"}` Unsupported Media Type @mkamranhamid

Comment: I've no idea about .net but by seeing your error I guess your target resource should be explicitly told what kind of data it should be receiving in body like this 
`'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959728/unsupported-media-type-on-asp-net-core-2-2-apicontroller) too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need this config

```
   routes.MapRoute(
     name: "api",
     template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

Instead use routing in your controller like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class YourController : Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
body: data,
```

can you try this?

```
body: JSON.stringify(data),
```